# Why does compilation of this simple C++ program using 'cpp' fail?

Tags: c++, c

I am a beginner in C++

I am average at C.

I have written the following code in C++ (`file.cpp`)

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

   std::cout<<"My name is ANTHONY";
}
```

Then I tried to compile the above code using `cpp file.cpp` but got some errors.
I don't know whats wrong

When I tried to compile my C program (changed `<iostream>` to `<stdio.h>` and `std::cout` to `printf`) using cc file.c, I didn't get any errors.

What is happening here?

Comment: What is happening is you need to read a [beginner book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) in C++. :)

Comment: @GMan : Which book did you read when you were a beginner?

Comment: @Anthony: I was a bad person and never really read a beginner book. I wish I had when I started.

Comment: @GMan : Then how are you so good at C++? According to me one cannot be  very good without reading any book. You did not read any book? I can't believe it.

Comment: @Anthony: I read beginner/intermediate books in C, and thought that meant I could learn C++. I was lucky and only picked up a million bad habits instead of two million. :) Spend a while reading intermediate/advanced books dropping those habits (still too prideful to read a beginner book), and I suppose it worked. But it was a huge waste of time compared to starting with a blank slate and reading a good beginner C++ book.

Comment: I think the title of the question is still vague. Some kind soul, please change the title to something meaningful.

Comment: @GMan:  You never read a beginner book?!  *zomg*  @Prasoon:  You have more than enough reputation to fix things like that...

Comment: @James : I am not very good at putting meaningful titles. :-)

Comment: @GMan : `still too prideful to read a beginner book`. Bad boy =).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Then I tried to compile the above code using **cpp file.cpp** but got some errors.

That is because [`cpp`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) is `C(C++)` preprocessor. It is a separate program invoked by the compiler (`g++`) as the first part of translation.

Try compiling your code using `g++ file.cpp`. :)

Comment: I say. Good catch, old chap.